# Passing 3+ dimensional arrays to Fortran subroutine from R

Tags: arrays, r, fortran

Is it possible to pass a 3+ dimensional array to a Fortran subroutine from R?

I am trying to leverage a Fortran library in my R package, but one of the Fortran subroutines works with a 3d array.

The Fortran code looks something like this:

```
SUBROUTINE foo(var1,arr)
implicit none
integer :: var1
integer, dimension(10,20,30) :: arr

!... do some calculations ...

end SUBROUTINE
```

And I have R pass in the arguments

```
.Fortran("foo", 1L, array(0L, dim = c(10, 20, 30))
```

but this crashes my R session. I guess that an `array` is unacceptable?

The error message I get is:

```
*** caught segfault ***
address 0x23d0018, cause 'memory not mapped'
```

Comment: How it crashes? Does it print something?

Comment: Does `L` mean `long`? Are you sure it is the same as `integer`?

Comment: In R `1L` is a 4 byte integer

Comment: @VladimirF `1L` is an integer in R. I am coding inside of R Studio, and the only error message I get is a popup saying "R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated". Let me try running the code in the terminal to see if another error message comes up.

Comment: A ha.. *** caught segfault *** address 0x3839018, cause 'memory not mapped' :(

Comment: The documentation suggests to me that you might not be able to pass objects with attributes, so I would try passing just an unnamed atomic vector and then using Fortran code to rebuild the structure you need. See section 5.2 of Writing R Extensions.

Comment: @BondedDust I was in the process of writing a wrapper to do just that (passing a vector and then restructuring it). As for using `.Call`, I thought that was for calling C/C++ code? Is it recommended to wrap fortran code into C/C++ and use `.Call` or `.External`?

Comment: Right. I amended my comment.